# What could cause a LoadError when requiring taglib-ruby in IRB?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, irb

Have gone through similar questions here, but have not been able to get this working.

I have RVM installed, and am trying to use a gemset I've set up for a Rails project to run a simple .rb file. After loading the gemset, I can load some of the gems through IRB, but not others.

```
1.9.2p290 :003 > require 'json'
 => true 
1.9.2p290 :004 > require 'taglib-ruby'
LoadError: no such file to load -- taglib-ruby
    from /Users/amoodie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/amoodie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/amoodie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.2p290 :005 > require 'dropbox-sdk'
LoadError: no such file to load -- dropbox-sdk
    from /Users/amoodie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/amoodie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):5
    from /Users/amoodie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.2p290 :006 > require 'pg'
 => true 
1.9.2p290 :007 > require 'rails'
 => true
```

All the above gems are in the same gemset. Trying to load rubygems returns false. I have no issue using accessing them through the Rails app, through.

Comment: You're probably requiring the wrong module names. Try `require 'taglib'` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using the Wrong Module Names

You're probably requiring the wrong module names. For example, try `require 'taglib'` instead of using the name of the gem or system package. If that works, you will probably need to do something similar with the require statement for the Dropbox library, too.